# Kamailio with Radius authentication

Tags: sip, radius, freeradius, kamailio

I have to implement **Kamailio with Radius authentication** process. Unfortunately, the available documentation for **auth_radius** module doesn't help me so much (I mean, I ve tried to use *auth_radius module* and *radius_www_authorize(realm)* function but without success). Are there some aditional steps that I should follow or I have to use new functions or modules? Can you provide me some tips in order to implement this authentication process?

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know exact answer.

Probably you should read auth_radius module documentation and tweak kamailio.cfg.

Also you can post your question to Kamailio mailing list, thats the best place to get answer for it.